# Trying to implement constructor pattern javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the values undefined even though it's populated. I think I've already populated it but feels like something is going wrong with the object's instance. That'd be great if someone can explain that where I'm going wrong.

```js
function Student(fn, sn, a, d)
{
  this.firstName = fn;
  this.lastName = sn;
  this.age = a;
  this.degree = d;
  this.displayStudent = displayStudent;
}

function displayStudent()
{
  console.log(this.fn);
  console.log(this.sn);
  console.log(this.a);
  console.log(this.d);
}

var studentObj = new Student("d", "r", 20,
                         "bachelors of science");
studentObj.displayStudent();
```

Comment: Why do you think `this.fn` and so on would refer to `this.firstName` and so on?

Comment: I tried Studen["fn"] instead of this.fn inside the function declaration but still the value I'm getting is undefined. Thanks.

Comment: @dr97 but you are setting `this.firstName` - you don't have a `this.fn` property on Student.

Comment: @VLAZ I got your point. thanks. I was making a dumb mistake.

Comment: @RandyCasburn: I did not want to get into the details... Your comment is also inaccurate, as typescript is not a facade but just another language that is transpiled to javascript... As far as I know javascript is not an object language so to speak but a prototype based one.
To complete this I'd like to add that I did put the "real" between quotation mark...

Comment: @MaxouMask. you are wrong.

Comment: @MaxouMask How would you use "real classes" in TS if TS is compiled into JS every time? You're only running JS in the end, so if you can't have "real classes" there, then it's not possible to have "real classes" in TS since you never RUN TS

Comment: @VLAZ: I get your point, I was referring to the 'class' keyword in TS when talking about real classes.

Comment: @RandyCasburn: Agreed accuracy is important. My mistake. Have a nice one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a typo, your code should be like this:

```js
function Student(fn, sn, a, d)
{
  this.firstName = fn;
  this.lastName = sn;
  this.age = a;
  this.degree = d;
  this.displayStudent = displayStudent;
}

function displayStudent()
{
  console.log(this.firstName);
  console.log(this.lastName);
  console.log(this.age);
  console.log(this.degree);
}

var studentObj = new Student("d", "r", 20,
                         "bachelors of science");
studentObj.displayStudent();
```

In your code you tried to print Student's "constructor" attributes instead of Student's "object" parameters you set.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. Sorry for making such silly mistake.

Comment: That is exactly why SO is here @dr97. You should accept this answer before any other false and misleading information is put here.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to display the Student constructor parameters
instead of displaying the Student properties, a method declared outside the constructor does not have access to the constructor´s parameters. To display the Student properties with the displayStudents() method do this.

```js
function Student(fn, sn, a, d)
{
  this.firstName = fn;
  this.lastName = sn;
  this.age = a;
  this.degree = d;
  this.displayStudent = displayStudent;
}

function displayStudent()
{
  console.log(this.firstName);
  console.log(this.lastName);
  console.log(this.age);
  console.log(this.degree);
}

var studentObj = new Student("d", "r", 20,
                         "bachelors of science");
studentObj.displayStudent();
```

Also when you declare methods outside the object constructor you should use the prototype property like this.

```js
function Student(fn, sn, a, d)
{
  this.firstName = fn;
  this.lastName = sn;
  this.age = a;
  this.degree = d;
}

Student.prototype.displayStudent = function()
{
  console.log(this.firstName);
  console.log(this.lastName);
  console.log(this.age);
  console.log(this.degree);
}

var studentObj = new Student("d", "r", 20,
                         "bachelors of science");
studentObj.displayStudent();
```

Comment: dont you know prototypes are bad

Comment: @KunalMukherjee - Why? What makes prototypes _bad_?

Comment: if you make your own custom prototype without knowing that it alread exists natively then it messes up the native one

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't make prototypes bad, that makes over writing native objects bad. Since `Student` is not a native object, using prototypes is just fine. It is the nature of the language and how it works. If you want a reference to how much prototypes are used, look at the jQuery source code.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee. Don´t satanize programmatic structures or tools to the extent of not using them ever, they are there for a reason and I don´t see the problem of using prototype here. prototype is a tool used for inheritance in javaScript

Comment: @KunalMukherjee you also shouldn't use variables, then, because you might clash with a global one thus interfering with the overall system behaviour. I expect you would think that is a preposterous suggestion to make and you'd be correct. It makes exactly as much sense as claiming "don't use prototypes because you might overwrite an existing one"

Comment: What's the reason for using prototypes when methods are declared outside the objects?

Comment: @uniBoi that way other programmers reading your code know that what they are looking at is a method or property added to the object, without reading the actual constructor.